# Populate data based on data in the other table

Tags: sql

Let's say I have table Goods and Brand.
[image: Table Example]

Does anyone know how to do this? I was thinking using join and union but confuse on how do I compose it.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a database? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is store already an extra table? If not, store is your n:m table, that holds at least an own sequence and two columns with the sequences from goods and brands.

Comment: I am still unaware of what you want, on the second hand only Images won't help you need to explain clearly what you want.

Comment: @Jonny yes it is a database

Comment: @AlexanderSchütz Store will be the result of union/join those 2 table.

Comment: @NK I have two tables in database and somehow I need to do some query so the result will be like Store table.

Comment: What technology do you want to display this data? Is it a web application? Are you using Sql Reporting Services? SQL isn't meant to mix rows of different types, that's what you do in the presentation layer of your application.

Comment: the result will be used in web application. I am thinking to create view for this. but first I want to know how to solve the problem above. My database is Oracle. So PL/SQL is welcomed also.
I am thinking that I need to use Union and Group by. But i don't know how to compose it so I can get that result.

Answer (score 1):

I thing you expecting to combine two tables.Then try this

```
select field name from Goods
union all
select field name from Brand
```

Comment: Hmm... it is close. But I want it to be grouped. I was trying to use group by but it is error. My database is oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to apply the grouping in your web application, not in SQL. Use a join between the first two tables as input. Depending on the tools available in your web application, it might be very simple to set the grouping. Often there will be some kind of datatable, which can use that join (example columns) as an input.

In your example, the join will have columns `Goods` and `Brand`. Set the grouping parameter of your data table control to `Goods`, and you'll have your grouping done automatically. Hard code your "Store" heading to it, and voilà, there's your table.

If you post what you use to build your web application, we might be able to provide some advice as to what control you can use.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no tool to set group by parameter. it has to be done through SQL. I am using Oracle APEX here.

Comment: What do you use to create the web application?